# How to get synonym creation history?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Each tag may have several synonyms. On synonyms page [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) you can see the synonym's creator. This is the user who started the process of synonymizing. In case if that done by a mod, no other users are needed to approve the synonym. If it was started by a regular user, it still can be approved by mod. The longest way is to get 4 more votes up, than votes down.

Is there a possibility to get some kind of synonym approval history? Or at least understand how many users were participated in that process for particular tag.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and don't think it's important enough to justify the devs doing something to show such a thing. Question is what you need it for?

Comment: @Shadow the history is needed for ... history needs, to investigate how we got that we got. That's almost the same situation like approving the suggested edits. But for edits we have history from the beginning. Currently I would like to know did regular users approve one specific synonym, or it was done by mod, because the synonym what I interested for is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not everything you want, but from [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) you can get:

- Score of the synonym. (You still do not know how many people voted - but at least you know the difference between the number of upvotes and the number of downvotes when the synonym was approved.)
- The user who suggested the synonym.
- The user who created the synonym. (Which will be the Community user if the synonym was created by voting of regular users. If it was approved by a mod, you'll see the name of the moderator.)

Here is a query [listing approved synonyms](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1237888/recently-approved-tag-synonyms) - ordered from the most recent one. Here is a query showing data about synonyms for the given synonym - as examples, it is applied to [code](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=code), [https](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=https) and [rss](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=rss).

If you're looking into this because some synonym seems unsuitable (and possibly needs to be removed), it is useful to know that from SEDE you can get separate lists even for synonymized tags. Example: [code](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1190392/find-questions-containing-the-given-tag?tagname=code) and [code-formatting](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1190392/find-questions-containing-the-given-tag?tagname=code-formatting). (So you find the questions which had the "old" tag when the synonym was created and the tag hasn't been changed since then. However, the synonymized tag is changed to the master tag if a question is edited after the creation of synonym. And all occurrences are changed if the two tags are merged by a moderator.)

You can check out the entries available in the TagSynonyms table here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677).

Since we're looking at the tag synonyms, here is a query [listing the pending tag synonyms](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1239539/pending-tag-synonyms). IIRC the [list on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) will only show those pending synonyms where you can actually vote.

Just as a curiosity, I will mention that the moderators have the possibility to suggest a synonym in such a way, that the synonym is still left for other users (regular users or moderators) to be approved: [Synonym by a moderator which needs approval?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3731)

Comment: Thank you for queries, I added non-Latin tag support for [one of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1803412/data-about-a-tag-synonym-supports-non-latin-tags?tagname=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C).